# duplicate lines of the database with incrementation of date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot for my back-end application, and i want to duplicate the row of the table automatically every day with the incrementation of the dates.
a row contain : **Id,Name,Age,BeginDate,Finishdate**

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the code you have so far or how you have tried to do it?

Comment: Sharing the related code and your tries on that will be helpful and can esaliy leads to solution

Comment: ben please check this, will be helpful when making questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a scheculed process to duplicate all rows at night. Is enough declare a method of a Spring bean with the following annotation

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
```

You will need add the `@EnableAsync` annotation to your Spring Boot configuration class.

A new field on table will be needed to know if record was duplicated previously